# uibutton working on ipad, but not iPhone

Tags: uibutton

code works on an ipad, but on iPhone the uibutton does not accept taps (and the action method does not get called).  on iphone, tapping the uibutton looks same as tapping a uilabel.  ios 8+ on both ipad and iphone.

Answer (score 0):

error had something to do with auto constraints.  i removed all constraints, redid the constraints, and now same code works correctly on both iPad and iphone.

Comment: Do you know what type of constraint caused this? I encounter the same problem and re-do the constraint but the problem refused to go away. My project has no complaint regarding the constraints.

Comment: @LocPham, i do not recall, too long ago and i switched projects.  you got 100% rid of all auto contraints, then redid them, but still have error?  when i delete the contraints on righ side of xcode storyboard screen, they turn to gray, but i think not fully deleted.  when i delete the constraints from left side of storyboard screen, they are totally gone.  i'm a beginner coder, hope this helps.